# Redirect to back to referrer page

Tags: python, flask

I am building an account settings page. I was thinking of having a few routes that only accept post request then edit the records and then go back the account settings page.

The problem is that there is two account settings pages. One for users and one for an  admin account.

The admin account_settings can use the same logic form the user account settings routes but If i use and post to use the user/account-settings route it returns back the user/account-settings route insted of the admin/user-account settings.

I was wondering how can flask returns back to the page it was on.

Comment: Could you use the `HTTP_REFERER` header that the browser sends to the server?

Comment: isn't HTTP_REFERER not reliable?

Comment: What do you mean by not reliable? Not guaranteed to be sent?

Comment: if the client disabled sending referrer information (for example, using a private/incognito browser Window). In such a case it will redirect to /.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

request.referrer will return back to the previous page. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/reqcontext/

Answer (score 1):

People usually solve this problem with session cookies (which you should have access to given that the user will be logged into an admin panel).

This is of course safter than using `HTTP_REFERER` (header sent by the client), as you control the contents of the session cookie entirely.

You could also pass a `?continue=http://...` thing in the URL.